# filter search a database set VB

Tags: database, vb.net, filter

I am very new to programming so i may be doing this all the wrong way, 
i have created a simple database where a user is creating new materials adding them to the database. this is all working fine,

i then have a form where a user can search the database, i am using the code below to search for a particular category in the database and this works fine

```
Angle_MatDataGridView.DataSource = Me.Raw_Material_DatabaseDataSet1.Angle_Mat.Select("cattext like'" & CatSearch.Text & "'")
```

What i now want to do is add another search in, so for example, above the user can search for the category "Plate" i also want to add a search for example material, so he user can search for "plate" AND "Steel"

running into alot of barriers, can someone help how i get around this? am i approaching this the right way?

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question as asked:

```
Angle_MatDataGridView.DataSource = Me.Raw_Material_DatabaseDataSet1.Angle_Mat.Select("cattext like'" & CatSearch1.Text & "' OR cattext like'" & CatSearch2.Text & "'")
```

That might not fulfil all your requirements but we'd have to know what they are in that case.